# how to reach a recursion formula for odd powers of cosine.

Tags: calculus, integration, recursion

Starting from the default cosine recursion formal (top equation) how do you reach the bottom recursion formula which is for odd powers of cosine?

$$ \int \cos^n x \,dx = \frac1n\, \sin x \cos^{n-1}x +
\frac{n-1}n \int \cos^{n-2}x \,dx $$

$$ I_{2n+1} = \int_0^{\pi/2} \cos^{2n+1}x \,dx =
\frac{2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdots(2n)}{3\cdot 5\cdot 7
\cdots(2n+1)}. $$

[Original image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9aP7.png)

[Original image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1yOH.png)

Comment: You reduce the power by 2 each time so you end up with the integral of cosine which is 1. If you keep track of the cascading fractions $n-1/n$ you get what you need. Observe that tha non-integral term vanishes at all the stages.

Comment: @GReyes Isnt the integral of cosine, sine?

Comment: Yes, but you have a definite integral between 0 and $\pi/2$, so you get $\sin\pi/2-\sin 0=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $I_n = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^{n}(x)dx$. Using the recursion formula, we have
$$I_n = \dfrac{n-1}{n}I_{n-2}.$$

Noting that $I_1=1$, we proceed by induction. For $n=1$, we have $I_3 = \dfrac{2}{3}I_1=2/3 $, thus we have a base case.

Suppose that the claim holds for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, i.e $I_{2n+1}=\dfrac{2\cdot 4\cdot \dots  (2n)}{1\cdot 3 \cdot \dots  (2n+1)}$ for some $n$; then we have
$$I_{2(n+1)+1}=I_{2n+3}=\dfrac{2n+2}{2n+3}I_n=\dfrac{2\cdot 4 \cdot \dots (2n)\cdot (2n+2)}{1\cdot 3 \cdot \dots (2n+1)(2n+3)}.$$
Then we are done by induction.